# How to exclude specific page from NextJS 13 app directory layout?

Tags: next.js

i have this folder structure:

```
app/view-all/layout.js
app/view-all/page.js
app/view-all/[itemId]
app/view-all/clothes
app/view-all/accessories
app/view-all/bags
```

All of these need to share an Aside componenent that i coded in **app/view-all/layout.js**. All of these *except* **app/view-all/[itemId]** which has its own **layout.js** file. How do i make it so the **app/view-all/layout.js** file doesn't include the /[itemId] page without changing its position in the structure?
I can't seem to find anything in nextjs' docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently it is not possible to ignore the layout file.

If I had to create such system, I would use optional params parameter of Layout Component.

Since your page view-all/[item-id]/page is providing item-id and view-all/page provides nothing, params will differ and you can use a if/else in your Layout Component to render what you want for each type of page.

Or, I would move parts that belong to each page in the page and not in the layout.

More about new nextjs13 params layouts: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#params-optional

Answer (score 0):

You cold to separete the those page file whith will be wraped by a layout of those whit won't, using "(foldername)" in the nomeclature of you folders. that won't change the path/URL of you aplication.

```
app/(app)/view-all/layout.js
app/(app)/view-all/page.js
app/(product)/view-all/[itemId]/page.js
app/(app)/view-all/clothes
app/(app)/view-all/accessories
app/(app)/view-all/bags
```

the folders named using "()" won't show up at the path of the navigators.
And you can add a "app/(product)/view-all/[itemId]/layout.js" to customise the products page layout. I hope it helpes you.